# Visual Studio 2013 hangs after deleting application file using InstallShield LE

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

When I try to delete an application file from the Application Files tab of an Install Project in Visual Studio 2013 (using InstallShield LE 2015) the file disappears from the list but all the Visual Studio menus are frozen and I cannot access any tab except the Install project. I have to close Visual Studio 2013 from Task Manager and when I re-open it the deleted file is still present.

MS only provide support for Visual Studio 2017 and newer and I'm reluctant to upgrade.

Comment: You're in luck, it is not a component that has anything to do with Microsoft or VS.  You need to get support from InstallShield.   Notable as a company that is very good at suckering programmers into using their freeware and can almost always get them to purchase an upgrade or maintenance contract.  They have no incentive to fix bugs like this, only to add them.

Comment: Did find a workaround - clicking the close icon on VS 2013 does bring up an offer to save the changed file. Restarting VS 2013 I find the deletions have worked.